# How do you test chained API calls in React with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jest-mock-axios

I have a save workflow in my react/redux app that requires two API calls. The second call only happens once the first call is completed successfully. The app is working great and I'm adding some automated end-to-end testing now.

I'm able to trigger the `onSave` function and verify the call to `saveRates`, but I'm having trouble getting the second API call to fire in my tests. Here's the code

```
function onSave() {
  // PUT to /rates/<id>
  dispatchProps.saveRates()
  .then(() => {
    // PUT to /apps/<id>
    dispatchProps.saveApplications()
    .then(() => {
      // Done
    });
  });
}
```

And this is the test code. I'm using Axios for the API calls in the app and `jest-mock-axios` to mock axios in my tests.

```
// At this point, `onSave` has been called


// This test passes
expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`rates/${rateId}`, { rate: { id: rateId }});
mockAxios.mockResponse({ status: 200 }, mockAxios.lastReqGet());

// This test fails with the error indicating that the expected API call was actually `PUT rates/<id>`
expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`app/${appId}`, { app: { id: appId, rate: rateId }});
mockAxios.mockResponse({ status: 200 }, mockAxios.lastReqGet());
```

It seems as though the promise from the first API call, `saveRates` hasn't been resolved. The `mockResponse` call resolves the promise but, using the jest debugger I can see that the call to `saveApplications` never happens.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios#axiosmockresponseresponse-requestinfo

How to I tell jest to wait until the next API call happens? Do I need to return the promises from the `onSave` call?

**UPDATE**

This works...so I suspect it can be solved with an `await` somewhere.

```
expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`taxes/event/${window.storeAdminTaxEventUuid}/rates/customer`, taxRatesResponse.data.customer);
    mockAxios.mockResponse({ status: 200 }, mockAxios.lastPromiseGet());

    setTimeout(() => {      
      expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`taxes/event/${window.storeAdminTaxEventUuid}/application/products`, taxApplicationsResponse.data);    
      mockAxios.mockResponse({ status: 200 });
    }, 0);
```